# Spring Framework & rpmbuild: Failed to get nest archive for entry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rpmbuild

I am working on creating an RPM for a java program with Spring Framework. I have been trying to understand why my jar files will not execute after being installed via RPM.

**--Steps I followed--**

1. Build my java program using Gradle to create a built snapshot of the jars.
2. Run the jar created. (It works!)
3. Create a .spec file to be used with `rpmbuild`.
4. Create an rpm using `rpmbuild`.
5. Yum local install the rpm.
6. Run the jar installed via rpm. (It doesn't work.)

**--The Issue--**
When trying to run my java jar installed via the rpm I receive an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get nested archive for entry BOOT-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:70)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open nested jar file 'BOOT-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar'
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:254)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:103)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:262)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:250)
    ... 6 more
```

I figured it has to do with something on how `rpmbuild` compresses the jars. The reason is because when I build my java project using **Gradle** I am able to run my jars just fine. However, if I try to run the jar from the `rpmbuild` I am creating I receive the compression exception.

**--My Code--**
Little background, the idea here is that I am using **Gradle** to build my java jars then I wanted to create an RPM out of the jars I create so that I could go and install the jars like an rpm.

Since I am using `rpmbuild` for to create my rpm these are my spec files:

```
Name:           ${NAME}
Version:        ${VERSION}
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Sample
AutoReqProv:      no
License:        GPLv3+
URL:            
Source0:        ${NAME}-${VERSION}.tar.gz

%description
Sample

%setup -q
%prep
cd ${SCRIPTPATH}
cp -rf ${NAME}/ \$RPM_BUILD_DIR/

%build

%install
rm -rf \$RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p \$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/sample/
cp -rf \$RPM_BUILD_DIR/${NAME}/${NAME}-sample-0.0.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar \$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/sample/sample-tool-1.0/sample-tool.jar

%clean
rm -rf \$RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
/opt/sample/

%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc

%changelog
```

The spec is built via a simple script that all you do is pass `${NAME}` and `${VERSION}` through it to populate those variables. Also `${NAME}-sample-0.0.10.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar` is my jar file that I am trying to just run. I am able to run the built non-rpm version of this jar fine without issues however trying to run the jar version installed via the rpm causes the compression exception.

I understand there are most likely other ways of creating an RPM that do not involve using `rpmbuild` but I am trying to learn how to use `rpmbuild`. In the past I am been able to create simple rpm that just do basic "Hello World" instructions but Spring Framework seems to be giving me trouble.

Comment: how do you launch the jar ? java -jar my.jar or ./my.jar. Could you provide your gradle script ?

Comment: I run the java -jar my.jar

Comment: If you think it is the JAR repacking, you can turn it off with the directive in your RPM spec file: `%define __jar_repack %{nil}` - see https://www.redhat.com/archives/fedora-devel-java-list/2008-September/msg00040.html for a lot more background and caveats.

Comment: `%define __jar_repack %{nil}` is useable for me

Answer (score 0):

do a small modification in your pom.xml file
here is the configurations,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
            <compress>false</compress> <!-- Add this line to disable compression -->
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

after configuring the changes run  "mvn clean install" and then execute the jar file `enter code here`